# Error when running OpenNI 2 class ( gcc 4.7.2 / ubuntu 12.10 )

Tags: c++, openni, gcc4.7

I'm trying to compile an run a very basic program given below (test.cpp) which calls the OpenNI class. You can see the files and dirs they're in here. Sorry that some characters screws up a little bit in the browser's encoding. I'm using the linux command: tree, if you know a better command tell me and I will update it.

[File Structure](http://evanrolfe.info/file_structure_for_stackoverflow_question.txt)

I'm following the guide [here](http://www.openni.org/wp-content/doxygen/html/getting_started.html), see "GCC / GNU Make".

```
#include < stdio.h > 
#include < OpenNI.h > 

using namespace openni; 

int 
main ( void ) 
{ 
    Status rc = OpenNI::initialize(); 

    if (rc != STATUS_OK) 
    { 
        printf("\nInitialize failed\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError()); 
        return 1; 
    } 

    printf("Hello, world!\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Here is what I'm running in the command line to compile it (gcc 4.7.2):

```
gcc test.cpp -I../OpenNI-2.0.0/Include -L/home/evan/Code/OpenNi/Init -l OpenNI2 -o test
```

This works fine but when I run ./test I get the following error:

```
Initialize failed 
DeviceDriver: library handle is invalid for file libOniFile.so 
Couldn't understand file 'libOniFile.so' as a device driver 
DeviceDriver: library handle is invalid for file libPS1080.so 
Couldn't understand file 'libPS1080.so' as a device driver 
Found no valid drivers in './OpenNI2/Drivers'
```

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instructions from your guide says, that

> It is highly suggested to also add the **"-Wl,-rpath ./"** to your linkage command. Otherwise, the runtime linker will not find the libOpenNI.so file when you run your application. (default Linux behavior is to look for shared objects only in /lib and /usr/lib).

It seems you have exactly this problem -- it can not find some libraries. Try to add proper rpath (seems to be /home/evan/Code/OpenNi/Init/OpenNI2/Drivers in your case) to your compilation string.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after compiling this little "Hello World" with Eclipse and trying to run it in the command line.
The "Wl,-rpath=./" thing did not work for me.
As also discussed [here](https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_camera/issues/10) it worked for me after setting some env. variables before execution:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/OpenNI2:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export OPENNI2_DRIVERS_PATH="/path/to/OpenNI2/Drivers"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/OpenNI2/Drivers:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

Somewhere I got the info that the first two lines should be enough but it was the third line which is important. I does also work just with the third line.